# How to conditionally project fields during aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a user document like:

```
{
    _id: "s0m3Id",
    _skills: ["skill1", "skill2"],
}
```

Now I want to unwind this document by the `_skills` field and add a score for each skill. So my aggregate looks like:

```
{ 
  '$unwind': {'path': '$_skills', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true},
},
{
  '$project': {
    '_skills':
      'label': '$_skills',
      'skill_score': 1
    },
  }
},
```

Sometimes the `_skills` field can be empty, however in this case I still want the user document to flow through the aggregation - hence the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` parameter. However, the problem I'm having is that it will project a `skill_score` (though with no `label`) onto documents which had empty `_skills` array fields. Thus, when I go to `$group` the documents later on, those documents now have a non-empty `_skills` array, containing a single object, namely `{skill_score: 1}`. This is not what I want - I want documents which had empty (or non-existent) `_skills` fields to not have any skill_score projected onto them.

So how can I **conditionally project a field based on the existence of another field**? Using `$exists` does not help, because that is intended for *querying*, not for boolean expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Updated**

This aggregation will set the value of `skill_score` to `0` if `_skills` does not exist, then use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) to remove the subdocument having `skill_score` equals to `0`:

```
db.project_if.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: '$_skills',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _skills: {
        label: '$_skills',
        skill_score: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: ['$_skills', undefined]
            },
            then: 0,
            else: 1,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $eq: [ "$skill_score", 0 ] },
        then: '$$PRUNE',
        else: '$$DESCEND'
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Result would be like:

```
[
  { "_id" : '', "_skills" : { "label" : "skill1", "skill_score" : 1 } },
  { "_id" : '', "_skills" : { "label" : "skill2", "skill_score" : 1 } },
  { "_id" : '' },
]
```

Comment: Right so that's what I have now. But ideally I what I want is:
`[
      { "_id" : '', "_skills" : { "label" : "skill1", "skill_score" : 1 } },
      { "_id" : '', "_skills" : { "label" : "skill2", "skill_score" : 1 } },
      { "_id" : '' },
    ]`

I want the final item to not have a `skill_score` field at all.

Comment: Updated it with $redact :)