# MongoDB Project with field existence check

Tags: mongodb

I have below document in DB ,

```
db.inventory.insertMany([
   { "stageId" : 1 , "eventId" : 1 , "type" : "DataCard", "content " : { "en" : "English Content" }},
   { "stageId" : 1 , "eventId" : 1 , "type" : "DataCard", "content " : { "en" : "English Content", "fr" : "French Content" }},
])
```

I need to  project the content based on fields existence. 
If french content exist then french otherwise English

```
{
    type : "DataCard",
    content : "English Content" 
}
{
    type : "DataCard",
    content : "French Content"
}
```

I used below query ,

```
db.getCollection('inventory').aggregate([{ $project: { content: {$ifNull: ['$content.fr', '$content.en'] } , type : 1}}])
```

But it only returns the type field alone.

Is there any way to cover this scenario ?

Even the simple query to project english content in all cases is only projecting the type field alone

```
db.getCollection('inventory').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project : {
                "type" : "$type", 
                "content" : "$content.en"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899777/how-to-conditionally-project-fields-during-aggregate-in-mongodb . does it helps ?

Comment: You have space in `content` field https://mongoplayground.net/p/dRLd7xgq8uz

Comment: Oh! My Bad, In Robo-3T the space at the end of the field is not noticeable . Let this question be here  , hope it helps some to project fields based on field availability.